# How to dynamically update an existing README.md with a list of WordPress plugins?

Tags: list, command-line, wordpress, gulp, readme

If possible, I'd like to automatically append a list of WordPress plugins onto an existing README file (preferably markdown). I've been fiddling around with this idea but so far I am only able to pipe file names within a given directory into a new file in JSON format by using gulp-filelist. Perhaps this is a start.

To be clear, the desired solution might be a command line tool that can be run intermittently; there is no need for real-time updates if such a thing is too much of a headache (or impossible). Additionally, while it would be excellent to see a list of *active* WP plugins and version numbers, a mere list of all *installed* plugins would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

> If possible, I'd like to automatically append a list of WordPress
>   plugins onto an existing README file

Use [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) to add all your references.

> To be clear, the desired solution might be a command line tool that
>   can be run intermittently

Use [gulp-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch) to monitor your plugins or list thereof. If you already have a file containing such a list, watch that file and run your inject task accordingly.

Wordpress uses bower components. That means that you have a *bower.json* file. Under "dependencies" you will see all your plug-ins.

i.e.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.5.0",
    ...
    ...
  },
```

Comment: I am referring to WordPress plugins, not project dependencies like Bootstrap, lodash, and fonts. In other words, I need a list of everything in wp-content/plugins/. For these, there is no such _bower.json_ file. Even then, I don't see an option for using gulp-inject to insert file names into markdown documents.

Comment: you can tell 'inject' what to inject with custom tag. In your case in your Readme.md file use something like `<wp-plugings></wp-plugings>` to indicate where to inject your list of plug-ins. Have you ckecked out [List Pligins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-plugins/) from wordpress?